# How to access cmd of another computer from my computer's cmd?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

How can I access the Command Prompt of another computer from my own computer's Command Prompt in Windows7?

I am hoping that I can do something like that into a batch file:

```
Enter \\ComputerA -u John -p 123
Run some commands on ComputerA
Leave ComputerA
Enter \\ComputerB -u Jane -p 123
Run some commands on ComputerB
Leave ComputerB
Return to on my computer's console
```

It's like in Task Scheduler, I can connect to another computer and do some stuff remotely from my computer.

Can I do this in cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the MS tool psexec (used to be sysinternals)

From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
```

You can enclose applications that have spaces in their name with quotation marks e.g.

```
psexec \\marklap "c:\long name app.exe"
```